# pthread library fails when called from static constructor code

Tags: c++, c, gcc, pthreads, glib

I have a C++ shared library object which incorporates the [GLib library](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/).

When I create a minimal test program with an **empty `main()`** function, and I link with the shared library, the program aborts immediately at runtime with the following GLib error message:

```
GLib (gthread-posix.c): Unexpected error from C library during 'pthread_cond_init': Invalid argument.  Aborting.
```

Since my main function is empty, the error must be happening in some pre-main initialization function somewhere.  So, using GDB I found that GLib has a static initialization constructor function (in `glib-init.c`) which it calls at runtime before `main()`.  Within that initialization function, it calls `pthread_cond_init`, which mysteriously fails.

Here is the complete backtrace:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: ~/example
warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at 0x2aaaaaaab000
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
GLib (gthread-posix.c): Unexpected error from C library during 'pthread_cond_init': Invalid argument.  Aborting.

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x0000003891830265 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000003891830265 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x0000003891831d10 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00002aaaab9aed32 in g_thread_abort (status=22,
    function=0x2aaaabcbdd2b "pthread_cond_init")
    at ~/libs/glib/gthread-posix.c:75
#3  0x00002aaaab9af349 in g_cond_impl_new ()
    at ~/libs/glib/gthread-posix.c:656
#4  0x00002aaaab9af39b in g_cond_get_impl (
    cond=0x2aaaac15f690 <g_once_cond>)
    at ~/libs/glib/gthread-posix.c:677
#5  0x00002aaaab9af4b2 in g_cond_broadcast (
    cond=0x2aaaac15f690 <g_once_cond>)
    at ~/libs/glib/gthread-posix.c:792
#6  0x00002aaaab9ab529 in g_once_init_leave (
    location=0x2aaaac160510 <g_define_type_id__volatile.11714>,
    result=6524000) at ~/libs/glib/gthread.c:682
#7  0x00002aaaaba34a2f in g_value_array_get_type ()
    at ~/libs/gobject/gboxed.c:132
#8  0x00002aaaaba41b28 in _g_param_spec_types_init ()
    at ~/libs/gobject/gparamspecs.c:1511
#9  0x00002aaaaba30c72 in gobject_init_ctor ()
    at ~/libs/gobject/gtype.c:4391
#10 0x00002aaaabb2bc36 in __do_global_ctors_aux ()
   from ./MYLIB.so
#11 0x00002aaaaad368eb in _init () from ./MYLIB.so
#12 0x00002aaab0180e60 in ?? ()
#13 0x000000389140d4ab in call_init ()
  from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#14 0x000000389140d5b5 in _dl_init_internal ()
   from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#15 0x0000003891400aaa in _dl_start_user ()
   from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#16 0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
#17 0x00007fffffffe6de in ?? ()
#18 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

So, my first thought was perhaps the `.so` file isn't properly linked with the pthread library.  So, I used the `ldd` utility to check how it is linking to pthread:

```
$ ldd MYLIB.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff56ed1000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00002b8a747bf000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00002b8a749db000)
        libpng12.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libpng12.so.0 (0x00002b8a74be5000)
        libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00002b8a74e09000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00002b8a7503d000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00002b8a75252000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00002b8a75456000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00002b8a75756000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00002b8a759da000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00002b8a75be8000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003891400000)
        libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00002b8a75f41000)
        libexpat.so.0 => /lib64/libexpat.so.0 (0x00002b8a761c6000)
```

So, it is properly linked with libpthread via `/usr/lib64/pthread.so.0`

So then I looked at the GLib source code that is failing on `pthread_cond_init`.  It's very straightforward.  I removed some `#ifdef` statements for clarity:

```
  pthread_condattr_t attr;
  pthread_cond_t *cond;
  gint status;
  pthread_condattr_init (&attr);

  cond = malloc (sizeof (pthread_cond_t));
  if G_UNLIKELY (cond == NULL)
    g_thread_abort (errno, "malloc");

  if G_UNLIKELY ((status = pthread_cond_init (cond, &attr)) != 0) <--- this fails
    g_thread_abort (status, "pthread_cond_init");
```

So nothing looks wrong there, and I doubt GLib would have any obvious error like this, considering it is used extensively throughout many major Linux codebases.

So, at this point, I'm out of ideas.  What are some possible and/or likely causes for this problem?  Is it possible this could be a order-of-initialization issue, where the pthread lib needs to perform some static initialization before GLib can use it?

Comment: When you compile and link, do you specify whatever flag your platform requires for pthreads support? (Probably `-pthread`.)

Comment: Which `glibc` version do you use?

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in `pthread_cond_init`, does it stop at `pthread_cond_init@@GLIBC_2.3.2`? Or is there another GLIBC number?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, yes I am compiling with `-pthread` and `-D _REENTRANT`

Comment: @4566976, I'm using glibc 2.5 - an very old version

Answer (score 0):

In `glibc-2.5` there are two versions of `pthread_cond_init`. The old one, which is probably used, has a comment that

> neither clocks other than CLOCK_REALTIME

are supported, and `EINVAL` can be returned.

In line [642](https://github.com/djdeath/glib/blob/master/glib/gthread-posix.c) of `gthread-posix.c` there's the call

```
pthread_condattr_setclock (&attr, CLOCK_MONOTONIC);
```

which probably causes the return of `EINVAL` from `pthread_cond_init`.

If you can recompile your `glib` you could undefine `HAVE_PTHREAD_CONDATTR_SETCLOCK`.

Otherwise I would update the `glibc` if possible.